# Iteration of string in for loop doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, for-loop

Being a beginner I am keen to sharpen my terrible Javascript skills. So I am tackling some Javascript challenges I found at [rmion.com](http://rmion.com/javascript-functional-programming-free-beginner-exercises/). I am stuck on **#4** (I really do mean stuck, I've done my best on my own before bringing it to stackoverflow).

The instruction is: *Write a function translate() that will translate a text into “rövarspråket”. That is, double every consonant and place an occurrence of "o" in between. For example, translate("this is fun") should return the string "tothohisos isos fofunon".*

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
var vowel = 'a,e,i,o,u';
newString = '';
function vowelCheck(character) {
  for (var i = 0; i < character.length; i++) {
    if (character !== vowel[i]) {
      return newString + ((character[i]+character[i])+'o');
    } else {
      return newString + (character[i]+'o');
    }
  }
}
vowelCheck('abc');
```

I need the loop to run for every character abc which should return:

```
a,o,b,b,o,c,o
```

However, because the function returns a value with a string length equal to the function's given parameter *.length* it stops running the loop.

```
vowelCheck("abc");
// returns "aao"
```

Is it possible with the code I've written to make function run for each letter in *vowelCheck("abc");*?

I haven't looked at [rmion](http://rmion.com/javascript-functional-programming-free-beginner-exercises/)'s given solution because I'm trying to see where I am going wrong. If it is not possible with what I've written, any hints would be great ^^ (I'm not looking for freebies)

Comment: Why it is expected to return `a,o,b,b,o,c,o` for the input word `abc`? Can you explain your idea?

Comment: Your expected result doesn't match the instruction; is that a concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is this line:

```
if (character !== vowel[i])
```

It's not really doing anything.

What you could do is use an array to hold the vowels:

```
var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
```

and then check to see if the character is in that array:

```
// if vowels does NOT contain the character...
if (vowels.indexOf(character[i]) === -1)
```

Finally:

```
return newString + ((character[i]+character[i])+'o');
```

will not return the complete string, only the first part of the string, and I don't think it will generate the output you want.

```
newString += ((character[i] + 'o' + character[i]));
```

will keep adding the substrings to the output string which you can then return at the end of the function.

[Here's a working example you can reference](http://jsfiddle.net/yb6amj3w/) if you want to.

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest, though an array isn't strictly necessary. `indexOf` will work on the string as well, but the string should really be just `'aeiou'` without the commas to prevent any false positives.

Comment: @Andy much obliged! I guess I have a lot of studying to do ^^>